# Php regex string needs more delimiters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regex to check the validity of an email address in a php script. I use the following string as my regex

```
$reg = "\/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})\$\/";
```

I keep getting an error:

```
 Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

I've done my best to escape all special characters. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are the two `\/` lines meant to be part of the regex or the delimiters? If they are the delimiters, they should not be escaped. I ask because the begin and end characters are between them.

Comment: You escaped too much. :)

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL bases on a more standards-compliant regex.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match tld's with 5 chars consider the example below.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You escape your delimiters, f.e:

```
$sCorrect = "/[a-z]/";
$sFalse = "\/[a-z]\/";
```

Even better, use:

```
filter_var($sVariable, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 4):

You escaped too many characters:

```
$reg = "/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+@([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/";
```

- The `/` regex delimiters (at the start and end of your regex) shouldn't be escaped
- The metacharacters `^` and `$` shouldn't be escaped.
- The dot needs not to be escaped (but can be) when it's in a character class
- The `@` needs not to be escaped (but can be)

Regardless, creating your own regex to validate email addresses can be tricky. Most likely you are disallowing valid emails (eg: `+` is a valid character you are not allowing) and/or allowing invalid ones. The standards for this are set by RFC 822, I believe - and they are loooooooong.

Just use `filter_var()` as suggested by Wesley. Or better yet, send an email to the supplied address. That's the best and most reliable way to determine if the address is

a) valid
b) belongs to the user

---

An interesting read: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

Comment: Good read, perhaps you like this one aswell: http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2009/12/28/your-email-address-is-invalid-please-enter-a-valid-address/

Comment: doesn't match .info, .aero or any tld with 5 chars.

Comment: @Tuga Read my entire answer. I merely fixed the OP's regex, I never claimed it's perfect. Actually I specifically pointed out the regex has got problems =/

Answer (score -1):

```
$reg = "/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b/i"
```

Works with the [new Gtld's](http://valideus.com/resources/gtlds-list/)

Explanation:

```
# Options: case insensitive
# 
# Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
# Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9._%+-]+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
#    A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
#    One of the characters “._%” «._%»
#    The character “+” «+»
#    The character “-” «-»
# Match the character “@” literally «@»
# Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9.-]+»
#    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
#    A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
#    The character “.” «.»
#    The character “-” «-»
# Match the character “.” literally «\.»
# Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z” «[A-Z]{2,6}»
#    Between 2 and 6 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{2,6}»
# Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

Comment: -1 Fails for `Abc\@def"@example.com`, `"Fred Bloggs"@example.com`, `$A12345@example.com`, `!def!xyz%abc@example.com` (and others) which are all valid emails according to the RFC standards.

Comment: Yes, I have. At least I am downvoting a demonstrably wrong answer (for the reasons mentioned above), instead of downvoting an answer I didn't bother to read in its entirety.

Comment: Not sure why you've deleted my comment but that's ok, good for you.

Comment: I didn't delete your comment; only moderators can do that (or the system deleted it because it got flagged by multiple users as offensive)

Comment: Here's what a RFC822 compliant regex looks like: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html