# Why won't this accept email addresses with a hyphen after the @?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

This is the code to sign up to receive email news updates on our site. It works great, unless the email address has a hyphen after the @, then it throws an error box:

```
> The page at http://www.MySite.com says:
> 
> Please Fix the following: 
> 
> E-mail
```

test-test@test.com works, but test@test-test.com does not. Any ideas?

from `email.js`:

```
    function checkSubmit(thisDept){

    var email = $('email').value;


    var message = "Please Fix the following: \r\n";




    var emailpat = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$/;
    if( !email.match(emailpat) ) {
        message += "E-mail \r\n";
    }





    if(message == "Please Fix the following: \r\n"){

            submitEmail(email,thisDept);

    } else {
            alert(message);
    }



    }


function submitEmail(email,thisDept){
        new Ajax.Updater( "EAlertContainer","php/ealerts.php", {
     method: 'post', parameters: { email: email } });
}
```

Edit: Thanks for all of your concerns about the vulnerability of the original code I posted. Just so I'm certain, the proper way to escape it is:

```
mysql_select_db("DATABASE",$dbx); 
$email=mysql_real_escape_string ($email); 
$queryx = "INSERT into master_email (emailid,cellmail,email) VALUES ('','','".$email."')";
```

Yes/no?

Comment: warning your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Something is missing - show the PHP code that fills the variable `$join` in `<? echo $join; ?>`.  I think your problem is in there, because there is no Javascript regex pattern in the code you posted

Comment: Since the code you posted doesn't have the words "Please Fix" in it, it's clearly not the source of the error. Please try to narrow down the problem to the actual part of the code that causes the error and post just that.

Comment: the provided code do not contain any validation. You should paste the validation code (which most likely is in the checkSubmit() JS function

Comment: Do you know a lot of domains containing a hyphen ?

Comment: @Daniel A. White: I actually noticed that while I was trying to figure out my current problem. I didn't write this code, I "inherited" it from the previous person who had my job.

Comment: Could you also post the code that generates the error? The code you posted now doesn't seem to check anything about email addresses, at least I can't see where the error message comes from.

Comment: Talk about cargo-cult programming.... Where exactly does that wall of code have "Please Fix the Following"? The code as posted does NOT generate your error message.

Comment: @Amine: Would that matter? A hyphen is a valid character, so it should be accepted.

Comment: 1. This code is ugly
2. `LIKE` is useless to simply test an equality

Comment: @Arjan : well there is a lot of flexibility in a email address... emails addresses having such specials characters tend to have the most problems in receiving emails ... because the flexibility is not always there on the SMTP server

Comment: @Amine: A hyphen in the domain name part is nothing special. If that's not accepted by the server then the validation sucks. (In fact, most complicated regexes to do email address validation do not allow all legal domain names, but that does not make this case right.)

Comment: @Dennis: You'll probably need to check the javascript files too.

Comment: @Arjan : from my experience, some servers tend to reject those emails. As a user, i will not take the risk to not receive an important email. As an application developer, I will probably inform my client that accepting an email address as valid does not mean it will be valid on any server specially those responsible of forwarding the email.

Comment: @Amine: warning a user could be a good idea, but that's by far not the same as just bluntly rejecting the email address.

Comment: I would refrain from using regex to validate email addresses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166239/php-regex-string-needs-more-delimiters/7166271#7166271

Comment: @NullUserException: Do you have an alternative for javascript? `filter_var()` is nice, but it is a PHP function, and in this case the validation is done client side.

Comment: @Arjan The alternative is *not* to validate emails. Or if you do, show a warning telling the user that they *might* have gotten their email wrong, but never stop them because you *think* it *is* wrong. The only reliable way to validate an email is by sending it to the supplied address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var emailpat = /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@\.]{2,}$/;
```

Email addresses should have just one @-sign, and that can't be the first character. After the @ you'll need at least one dot followed by 2 or more letters.

And yes, this also accepts email addresses that are not valid. If you want to be sure that the user enters a valid email address, you should send an email to the address and wait for the user to take action (ie enter a code that's in the email).

**Edit**

Updated regex so the domain part is no longer restricted to roman alphabet TLDs. Other alphabets are allowed, although probably not very common (yet). See wikipedia for [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%BC%CE%AE).

Comment: I found another option - do you see any downside to this? 
`/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;`

Comment: Well, yes. It does not allow all legal characters in the local part (`! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ { | } ~` and the backtick) and it does not accept new TLD's like `.travel` and `.museum`. And it doesn't accept internationalized domain names, but I'll have to update my answer to fix that too. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.δοκιμή )

Comment: Updated answer to be even less restrictive.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain? Also, do you have an alternative javascript solution?

Comment: Upvoted you for being the only one to focus on my actual question and not ancillary problems with the code I posted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$queryr = sprintf("SELECT emailid FROM master_email WHERE email LIKE '%s' LIMIT 1",
          mysql_real_escape_string($email));
```

and do the same for the insert query.

Also, you're just asking for a SQL Injection :P

Comment: That's not the correct way to escape a query. In fact, you don't want to escape the whole query, but just `$email`.

Comment: _The page at http://www.MySite.com says: Please fix the following_ is a Javascript alert message, not produced by PHP.

Comment: Can you please provide the page in which this happens?

Comment: don't post the url or you will lose your entire database within 10 minutes, thanks to the obvious sql injection attack.  Seriously, take the page offline NOW!

Comment: wouldn't the right way to escape it be 
    `mysql_select_db("DATABASE",$dbx);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string ($email);
    $queryx = "INSERT into master_email (emailid,cellmail,email) VALUES ('','','".$email."')";`