# Email verification regex failing on hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I'm attempting to verify email addresses using this regex: `^.*(?=.{8,})[\w.]+@[\w.]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

It's accepting emails like `a-bc@def.com` but rejecting emails like `abc@de-f.com` (I'm using the tool at http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/ for testing).

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: This might be of use to you:http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation#300862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here is the explaination:

In your regualr expression, the part matches a-bc@**def.com** and abc@**de-f.com** is `[\w.]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

It means:

- There should be one or more digits, word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), and whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) or '.'.  See the [reference of '\w'](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- It is followed by a '.',
- Then it is followed one or more characters within the collection `a-zA-Z0-9`.

So the **-** in `de-f.com` doesn't matches the first  `[\w.]+` format in rule 1.

### The modified solution

You could adjust this part to `[\w.-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$`. to make **-** validate in the @string.

Answer (score 1):

Because after the `@` you're looking for letters, numbers, `_`, or `.`, then a period, then alphanumeric. You don't allow for a `-` anywhere after the `@`.

You'd need to add the `-` to one of the character classes (except for the single literal period one, which I would have written `\.`) to allow hyphens.

`\w` is letters, numbers, and underscores.

A `.` inside a character class, indicated by `[]`, is just a period, not any character.

In your first expression, you don't limit to `\w`, you use `.*`, which is 0+ occurrences of *any* character (which may not actually be what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Use this Regex:

```
var email-regex = /^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@\.]{2,}$/;
```

It will accept `a-bc@def.com` as well as emails like `abc@de-f.com`.

You may also refer to a similar question on SO:

[Why won't this accept email addresses with a hyphen after the @?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180886/why-wont-this-accept-email-addresses-with-a-hyphen-after-the)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use a regex like this to allow any email address.

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex works:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+[-.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[-A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[-A-Z|a-z]{2,})+
```