# Regular expression for allowing hypens in email domain validation

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core-2.0

I have a domain name validation to be kept for a field .For this purpose I use 
[DataType(DataType.Url)](a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations library of .net).
In this I am not able to allow hypen in between anywhere. What can be the possible change I can make to allow hypen here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Regular Expression

```
[RegularExpression("^.*(?=.{8,})[\\w.]+@[\\w.-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

For more info about excepting hyphen in domain using regex

[Email verification regex failing on hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178024/email-verification-regex-failing-on-hyphens)